# Send Nodemailer e-mail with Namecheap email and nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nodemailer, namecheap

I am trying to send an email to my mailcheap account with nodejs and nextjs. For reference I followed this tut [nodemailer and nextjs](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/coding-a-contact-form-with-next-js-and-nodemailer-d3a8dc6cd645)

just can't seem to connect to it. My email is pointing correctly to vercel which is where I am hosting my app. As I can email myself directly without nodejs.

This is the code

```
require('dotenv').config()


export default function (req, res) {
    
    let nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        port:'465',
        host:'mail.privateemail.com',
        auth: {
            user: 'lessons@teacher-esl.com',
            pass: process.env.PASS,
        },
        secure: true,
    });
    
    const mailData = {
        from: 'randomemail@hotmail.com',
        to: 'lessons@teacher-esl.com',
        subject: `Message From ${req.body.name}`,
        text: req.body.message,
        html: <div>{req.body.message}</div>
       }

       transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
        if(err)
          console.log(err)
        else
          console.log(info)
      })
      res.status(200).end()
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

In the terminal I keep getting missing credentials for "PLAIN".

Comment: Did you find your way around it?

Answer (score 3):

You are authenticating with `lessons@teacher-esl.com` but trying to send the mail with `randomemail@hotmail.com`.

That's where the problem lies.

If you want to send mail to `lessons@teacher-esl.com` then you would have to do this:

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:'mail.privateemail.com',
    port:'465',
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'randomemail@hotmail.com',
        pass: <randomemail-pass>,
    },
});
```